# Responsive iframe content: scale d3 to iframe size

Tags: html, css, iframe, d3.js, responsive-design

I'm trying to put some simple d3 into an iframe. I want the content of the iframe to scale with the size of the screen.

I'm trying to make this method work: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/.

The corresponding jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/812y03ot/3/.

HTML

```
<div class="video-container">
   <iframe src="http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/airports.html"
   frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The content of the iframe does not scale when I reduce the window size.

I do not want the content of the iframe itself to be respond to the reduced window size. I just want it to scale down when the window sized is reduced.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adapting this. http://jsfiddle.net/oxvkdcfy/

```
    <style>
    #wrap { width: 600px; height: 390px; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
    #frame { width: 800px; height: 520px; border: 1px solid black; }
    #frame {
        -ms-zoom: 0.75;
        -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform: scale(0.75);
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
</style>
```